# Aggregate/Group table rows in SQL if a column has a specific value

Tags: sql, xslt, sql-server-2005

I am working with a rather hairy Stored Proc which returns XML (the XML is transformed with a stylesheet and printed out to a page; essentially a GridView in XML).  I have a requirement to aggregate multiple rows (with the same ID, of course) into a single row *only if* the value of a particular column is not one of two specific values (in which case the columns are not aggregated).

In effect I need to do the following (in pseudocode):

```
select quoteID, customerName, shippingCharges, description, /*other columns*/
from quotes q
    inner join customers c on q.customerID = c.customerID
where shipDate between @fromDate and @toDate
for xml explicit

if description != "Insurance" and description != "Pickup":
    /*aggregate the rows for that quoteID into one single row
      adding together charges and the like as needed*/  
else:
    /*nothing - okay to have multiple rows*/
```

How should I go about handling this type of logic?  My first guess would be to put all the values into a temp table (or CTE) and then somehow check all of the data to see if I need to extract and combine rows but I'm drawing a blank as to how that actually is done, which is usually an indicator it's *not* the correct way of doing it...

Would this be better (and perhaps easier?) to do in the XSL transformation file instead?  My choices are limited to three options:

1. Aggregate in the stored procedure, leave XSLT untouched
2. Aggregate in the XSLT, leave stored procedure untouched
3. This can't be achieved with the way the data is being returned currently (or can't be achieved without lots of time-consuming workarounds)

**EDIT**

One of the issues I'm facing is that the records will usually have the same ID field, and therefore the totals are coming out incorrect because I am summing the whole record (which calculates the total for the field I want *and* the field that I don't want).

For example a record might be something like:

```
1234    Insurance           54.65
1234    Shipping Charge     160.00
1234    Some Other Charge   15.00
```

and I would want the finished result to be like this:

```
1234    Shipment    175.00
1234    Insurance   54.65
```

what's happening is this:

```
1234    Shipment    229.65
1234    Insurance   229.65
```

and it's throwing the totals off.

The strategy I was using was to create a CTE called "AggregateData" that sums up the various amounts and groups by the ID and the Description; this fails because it gives the above result (sums for each description, so the value appears twice and is added twice on the report).  The closest I have gotten is to NOT group it by the Description but instead wrapping it in the `Max` function (Yes, I know that's not a good idea).  This gives me the correct totals but the description isn't accurately being reflected e.g. some records should be "Insurance" but are showing "Shipment" instead.

Comment: Can something like `GROUP BY CASE WHEN description in ('Insurance,Pickup') THEN customerID ELSE 1 END` work? Have you got a guaranteed unique column that can be used in the case that you don't want any grouping?

Comment: I don't think you should duplicate data. XSLT is capable of doing that.

Comment: How (by what rule) do the `Shipping Charge` and `Some Other Charge` descriptions transform into `Shipment`?

Comment: That's the catch.  The requirement is to "roll up the row into one unless the Description is "Insurance" or "Pickup".  I was going to use a simple case statement e.g. `case when Description in ('Insurance', 'Pickup') then Description else 'Shipment' end as [ShipmentDescription]` but the problem is that either the rows aren't rolled into one (it shows "Shipment Charge" and "Some Other Charge" as separate entries) or it includes "Shipment Charge" in the sum, throwing off the total amount.

Comment: I mean, you seem to be grouping on something that is represented in the sample outputs as `1234` (maybe that's `quoteID`, I'm not sure). So, is `'Shipment'` something that replaces `'Shipping Charge'` and `'Some Other Charge'` *for `1234` only* or should it replace descriptions (which are neither `'Insurance'` nor `'Pickup'`) for any other value apart from `1234` as well?

Comment: Yes, 1234 is basically the QuoteID.  'Shipment' replaces the Description line for any value where the description is NOT 'Insurance' or 'Pickup'.  But sometimes the same QuoteID will have 2+ line items, and I need to combine the ones that DON'T have a description of 'Insurance' or 'Pickup' and sum up *only* the values from that (so if there was 2 records that were summed and one that was "Insurance", there should be two rows: One with the sum of the two, and one that just has the value for the "Insurance" row, which wasn't added to the sum).  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to write two queries and union the results

```
select <columns>
where description not in('Insurance','Pickup')
group by  <some columns)
union all
select <columns>
where description in('Insurance','Pickup')
```

Comment: I think the group by goes on the Insurance/Pickup query...?

Comment: That works wonderfully.  My only question is there *might* be a requirement to know which rows were grouped together and which weren't (to display a different description) - if that does end up being a requirement how would I handle that?

Comment: @Wayne M: You could add a column, `IsGrouped`. The above query would then change like this: `select 1 as IsGrouped, <columns>... union all select 0 as IsGrouped, <columns>...`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
  customerName,
  quoteID,
  description = CASE
    WHEN description IN ('Insurance', 'Pickup') THEN description
    ELSE 'Shipment'
  END,
  shippingCharges = SUM(shippingCharges)
FROM quotes q
  INNER JOIN customers c ON q.customerID = c.customerID
GROUP BY
  customerName,
  quoteID,
  CASE
    WHEN description IN ('Insurance', 'Pickup') THEN description
    ELSE 'Shipment'
  END
```

You must have noticed that the same CASE expression is repeated twice here. You can avoid it by using an ordinary subselect:

```
SELECT
  customerName,
  quoteID,
  description,
  shippingCharges = SUM(shippingCharges)
FROM (
  SELECT
    customerName,
    quoteID,
    description = CASE
      WHEN description IN ('Insurance', 'Pickup') THEN description
      ELSE 'Shipment'
    END,
    shippingCharges = SUM(shippingCharges)
  FROM quotes q
    INNER JOIN customers c ON q.customerID = c.customerID
) s
GROUP BY
  customerName,
  quoteID,
  description
```

or a CTE:

```
WITH preparedList AS (
  SELECT
    customerName,
    quoteID,
    description = CASE
      WHEN description IN ('Insurance', 'Pickup') THEN description
      ELSE 'Shipment'
    END,
    shippingCharges = SUM(shippingCharges)
  FROM quotes q
    INNER JOIN customers c ON q.customerID = c.customerID
)
SELECT
  customerName,
  quoteID,
  description,
  shippingCharges = SUM(shippingCharges)
FROM preparedList
GROUP BY
  customerName,
  quoteID,
  description
```

You might also want to add some other columns, as needed.